# disable media command center when webview playing video

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have wkwebview with video youtube url, whenever i pressed play button, i'd like to media command center notification not showing, how to do that? i already tried this code below, but it's not working, is there any idea?

```
UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```